# SOLVED: Python interacting with VLC through Tkinter: I want to be able to change between videos

Tags: python, tkinter, youtube, vlc

I am making a python tkinter utility that makes a youtube search, brings up the first 6 results, and than plays the chosen of those results through a vlc instance.

The problem I have, is that when I try to change the video, it just opens a second VLC instance, and two musics start playing at the same time.

**So my question is: how do I use the same instance of vlc, to first play one piece of music, and then the next. Or if necesary, how do I destroy the instance of VLC to make the next one.**

Here is the code I tried; the experiment that doesnt work is within the function "func" (not the one that is made into comments). The code is by the way not my actual project, but just an experiment.

```
import vlc  
import time
import pafy
from tkinter import *

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yV25KhUH1BE"                                                                                   
win = Tk()
pause = 0

#def func():
#   global pause
#   pause = -(pause-1)
#   player.set_pause(pause)

def func():
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrxLttEc8do"
    video = pafy.new(url)                                                                                                                       
    best = video.getbestaudio()                                                                                                                 
    playurl = best.url
    media=instance.media_new(playurl)
    media.get_mrl()
    player.set_media(media)

btn = Button(win,
                    text = "Change video",
                    command =  func)



video = pafy.new(url)                                                                                                                       
best = video.getbestaudio()                                                                                                                 
playurl = best.url 

instance = vlc.Instance()
player = instance.media_player_new()                                                                                                         
media=instance.media_new(playurl)
media.get_mrl()
player.set_media(media)
player.play()
btn.pack()



win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example code works fine, it doesn't play multiple songs.

I think that in your actual code you are calling `player = instance.media_player_new()` whenever you play a new song. Make sure this is piece of code is outside of the function and only ever called once.

Comment: Thank you!
I also found another command, namely this:
instance.vlm_stop_media(playurl).
So I solved my problem. 
I managed to finish my project as well; a minimalistic GUI to listen to music on youtube without having to deal with any user interface of youtube.

Comment: @WillemvanHouten you can post your answer and accept it. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)